# How can I extract form data from within the ASP.NET Web API OnActionExecuting Filter method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to extract **form** data from within the `OnActionExecuting` method of an ASP.NET Web API Action Filter so I can write it to a log file.

My code looks like this:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext ctx)
    {
        if (ctx.Request.RequestUri.Query.StartsWith("admin/")) return;

        try
        {
            _loggingService.LogRequest(new RequestLogModel
            {
                Handler = ctx.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                Uri = ctx.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri,
                RequestType = ctx.Request.Method.Method,
                RequestFrom = ctx.Request.RequestUri.Host,
                QueryString = ctx.Request.RequestUri.Query,
                FormData = // Need to get form-data here
            });
        }
        catch { }
```

I can't seem to work out how to get the form data from the request. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the form data in the request's content.

For more information on reading the multipart/form-data content using ReadAsMultipartAsync(...), check out this tutorial, [Sending HTML Form Data](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2).